# systemd Before and After declarations

Tags: systemd, services, dependencies

The definition given in the man for systemd unit is a bit unclear: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

> If a unit `foo.service` contains a setting `Before=bar.service` and both
>   units are being started, `bar.service`'s start-up is delayed until
>   `foo.service` is started up.
>   [...]
>   `After=` is the inverse of `Before=`, i.e. while `After=` ensures that the
>   configured unit is started after the listed unit finished starting up,
>   `Before=` ensures the opposite, that the configured unit is fully
>   started up before the listed unit is started.

Lets say I have `a.service` and `b.service`. I want `a.service` to start up completely before `b.service` because `b.service` depends on `a.service`.

After reading the aforementioned man page I couldn't find any conclusive explanation on whether:

- You **only** need to specify `Before=b.service` in the `a.service` unit file
- You **only** need to specify `After=a.service` in the `b.service` unit file
- You need **both** `After=a.service` in the `b.service` unit file **and** `Before=b.service` in the `a.service` unit file

**Which do I need to declare dependencies for systemd unit files? Does it matter?**

Comment: If `b` depends on `a`, aren't you looking for `Wants` or `Requires` or `Requisite` anyway?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with your units’ declarations?

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz I do have `Requires` as I need a hard fail for `b` if `a` hasn't started. However according to the aforementioned man page:
`
If a unit foo.service requires a unit bar.service as configured with Requires= and no ordering is configured with After= or Before=, then both units will be started simultaneously and without any delay between them if foo.service is activated.
`

Comment: @Stephen Kitt  I haven't tried experimenting yet as I am translating a large project which includes *numerous* upstart jobs to systemd services and they all have many dependencies. Give me a few weeks and I will get back to you ;)

Comment: What I meant was that you could answer your own question with a simple experiment involving your two `a` and `b` example units; no need to wait until you’ve finished translating all your upstart jobs!

Comment: Sounds like an experiment worth doing! .... outside of working hours.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You only need one of `After=` or `Before=` in your pair of units. You might prefer this from the man page for `systemctl`:

> --after ... any After= dependency is automatically mirrored to create
>          a Before= dependency.

Use this option with `list-dependencies` to check what you think systemd should be doing. Eg

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies --after timers.target
timers.target
* |-sysstat-collect.timer
* |-sysstat-summary.timer
* |-systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
* `-unbound-anchor.timer

$ systemctl list-dependencies --before sysstat-collect.timer
sysstat-collect.timer
* |-sysstat-collect.service
* |-shutdown.target
* `-timers.target
```

If you are converting from `upstart` you might get some hints from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), and you could read all the blogs listed [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) under the heading *The systemd for Administrators Blog Series*.